# Observable from more than one BehaviorRelay RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I am trying to achieve a subscription of 3 different BehaviorRelay using RxSwift. The idea is following:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

class ClassA{

    var br1 = BehaviorRelay(value: "BR1_1")
    var br2 = BehaviorRelay(value: "BR2_1")
    var br3 = BehaviorRelay(value: "BR3_1")

    /* Some other variables */

}
let classA = ClassA()


class ClassB:CustomStringConvertible{
    let classA:ClassA

    var description: String{
        return "\(br1.value), \(br2.value), \(br3.value)"
    }

    var br1:BehaviorRelay<String>{
        return classA.br1
    }
    var br2:BehaviorRelay<String>{
        return classA.br2
    }
    var br3:BehaviorRelay<String>{
        return classA.br3
    }

    init(classA:ClassA) {
        self.classA = classA
    }

}
let classB = ClassB(classA: classA)

classB.br1.asObservable().subscribe { (value) in
    print(value)
}

classA.br1.accept("BR1_2")
```

It prints:

```
next(BR1_1)
next(BR1_2)
```

By doing that I am "populating" my ClassB with objects from ClassA and by setting a subscription to the objects in ClassB i can react to the next events.

However, I would like to create a function such as:

```
func reactingFunction(br1:BehaviorRelay<String>, br2:BehaviorRelay<String>, br3:BehaviorRelay<String>){
    /**/
}
```

to be called every time any of the br produces onNext event. Can I create a mix subscription for all of them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out a solution by implementing CombineLast:

```
Observable.combineLatest(classB.br1, classB.br2, classB.br3).subscribe(onNext: { (br1, br2, br3) in
    reactingFunction(br1: br1, br2: br2, br3: br3)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Then I have changed the reactingFunction to accept only the values:

```
func reactingFunction(br1:String, br2:String, br3:String){
    print("Reacting Function -> \(br1) & \(br2) \(br3)")
}
```

From the example:

```
classA.br1.accept("BR1_2")
classA.br1.accept("BR1_3")
classA.br1.accept("BR1_4")
classA.br1.accept("BR1_5")
classA.br2.accept("BR2_2")
classA.br3.accept("BR3_2")
classA.br2.accept("BR2_3")
```

It prints:

```
Reacting Function -> BR1_1 & BR2_1 BR3_1
Reacting Function -> BR1_2 & BR2_1 BR3_1
Reacting Function -> BR1_3 & BR2_1 BR3_1
Reacting Function -> BR1_4 & BR2_1 BR3_1
Reacting Function -> BR1_5 & BR2_1 BR3_1
Reacting Function -> BR1_5 & BR2_2 BR3_1
Reacting Function -> BR1_5 & BR2_2 BR3_2
Reacting Function -> BR1_5 & BR2_3 BR3_2
```